# How to access the net.conn from a http connection in Golang?

Tags: http, go, http2

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
package main

import (
   "io"
   "net/http"
   "fmt"
   "net"
)

const (
    PORT       = ":443"
    KEY   = "./localhost.key"
    CERT = "./localhost.crt"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world! :)")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServeTLS(PORT, CERT, KEY, nil)
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is to use the net.Conn that is created when a client reaches my host. The reason behind this is to use golang.org/x/net/http2 in order to create custom frames and edit the transmission of data at a lower level. And for example http2.NewFramer requires a writer and a reader, which I guess would be the actual net.Conn in both cases.

I am pretty to new to Golang so any advice on how to improve myself is well welcomed. Thank you in advance everyone! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the underlying socket of a net/http response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531993/accessing-the-underlying-socket-of-a-net-http-response)