# Request Timeout while uploading image

Tags: node.js, ajax, go, timeout, fetch

Am developing web application using **golang** for web server and frontend with **reactJS** and **nodeJS** to serve the frontend. I have two issue while uploading images that are big `(currently am testing with 2.9 mb)` the **first** one am getting is a **timeout** within 10 second saying request timeout at the browser side but the upload is successfully uploaded to the database. The **second** issue is the request is being duplicated two times and as a result the request is saved to the database two times.  I have searched on stack overflow but it doesn't seem to work.

#### First Option

Here is the code using ajax call i.e. fetch from isomorphic-fetch

Following suggestion to implement a timeout wrapper at https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175

```
static addEvent(events){
    let config = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: events
    };

    function timeout(ms, promise) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {

                reject(new Error("timeout"))
            }, ms)
            promise.then(resolve, reject)
        })
    }

    return timeout(120000,fetch(`${SERVER_HOSTNAME}:${SERVER_PORT}/event`, config))
    .then(function(response){
        if(response.status >= 400){
            return {
                "error":"Bad Response from Server"
            };
        }else if(response.ok){
            browserHistory.push({
                pathname: '/events'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The request timeout still occurs within **10 seconds**.

#### Second Option

I have tried a different node module for the ajax call i.e. **axios** since it has a timeout option but this also didn't fix the timeout issue.

#### Third Option

I tried to set read timeout and write timeout on the server side similiar to https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/

```
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:         ":9292",
    Handler:      router,
    ReadTimeout:  180 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 180 * time.Second,
}
```

Again am getting request timeout at browser side within **10 seconds**.

what shall I do to fix or point me if i made a mistake ?

Comment: Can you test the server endpoint separately for file upload, e.g. using `curl` cmd? it seems timeout is happening at JS app side.

Comment: I have tested using curl ...                                                                      `curl  -F "eventTitle=Food festival"  -F "price=15"  -F "quantity=100" -F "startDate=2017-06-22 3:04 PM" -F "endDate=2017-06-22 3:04 PM"  -F "eventImage=@/Downloads/20160825_151253.jpg" localhost:9292/event
` Got Request Timeout at the terminal.   @jeevatkm

Comment: Tried with --max-time flag. `curl --max-time 120  -F "eventTitle=Food festival"  -F "price=15"  -F "quantity=100" -F "startDate=2017-06-22 3:04 PM" -F "endDate=2017-06-22 3:04 PM"  -F "eventImage=@/Downloads/20160825_151253.jpg" localhost:9292/event`. Still request timeout is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, Can you register `http.Server.ConnState` func? and observation connection state changes happens at server instance. Is this path is correct `@/Downloads/20160825_151253.jpg`?, typically Downloads directory resides inside the user home.

Comment: I have implemented http.Server.ConnState func. Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531993/accessing-the-underlying-socket-of-a-net-http-response Got the following output                    `CONN STATE: new, &{{0xc4202e8150}}
CONN STATE: active, &{{0xc4202e8150}}
Image GUID UUID 99600a33-b2cf-47b2-b2bc-58c0c4dfd18a
CONN STATE: idle, &{{0xc4202e8150}}
CONN STATE: closed, &{{0xc4202e8150}}` @jeevatkm

Comment: In between the conn state there is image guid that i will use later while uploading image to s3. You are correct about the path is under user home directory, i removed for clarity purpose. @jeevatkm

Comment: Now please use the connection state to debug your program to see does connection aborted by client or server.

Comment: Can you give me an example on debugging connection state ? @jeevatkm

Comment: Making an example at my end is not helpful for you. Basically when you observe connection state changes with logging the time it took on each state will give you an insights of "is it caused by your middlewares" or "is it dropped by client end". If you could create a working example with an issue you're facing and pass it on to me. I will take out sometime to analyze your code and share my observation. This is the best I can do for you.